# Is there a VSCode extension for auto-validating brackets?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, code, extension

I'm looking for an extension for VScode that can auto-validate brackets in code or highlight mismatched or invalid bracket arrangements. I've seen extensions that colorize brackets, which is helpful, but still leaves all of the work of validating them to be done manually by the user. For example:

```
([{)]}
```

will get colorized perfectly despite being invalid.

I'm looking for something that will automatically highlight unmatched and malformed bracket syntax. I'm quite surprised I wasn't able to find anything better than these colorizers